# Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, gradle, aapt2

does anyone know what is this error and how can I fix this?
I am trying to open a source code from Mumble and stucked with this error

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:352: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\NP\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows.jar\1d0ef7dbf7bb928283477115487f45e4\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
    C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential-3.1.3\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
    --manifest\
    C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
    -o\
    C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
    -R\
    @C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
    --auto-add-overlay\
    --java\
    C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
    --custom-package\
    com.morlunk.mumbleclient\
    -0\
    apk\
    --output-text-symbols\
    C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
    --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please, provide some code. That will be very helpful.

But, for now as the error shows:

> Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows Daemon #0

It means you must have some error in your XML files (layout files or drawable files), check your recent history of your XML file if you are working on Android Studio

**right click on xml file-> Local history-> show History**

or look for any error that XML file is showing.

> values.xml:352: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.

And also refer to this error in values.xml file

Comment: Your comment made me realize I needed to change my compile sdk to 28. Thank you.

Comment: In my code i used  <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/greyDark"
                    tools:ignore="MissingClass" />      ===============>>>>  its shwoing resource linking failed.

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me twice, and both times it was an xml spelling error, and the error message was not very useful. The best way to identify a problem is to Analyze -> Inspect code -> search for clues in the "Syntax error" and find the xml with an error.

Comment: Very useful for ur help!

Answer (score 6):

I get this error while creating the legacy icons (Image asset) tool - I find that the Android studio does not close `<Vector>` tag in `ic_launcher_foreground.xml`. I have to fix these errors by adding manually the close tag `</vector>`

Comment: Same problem after creating a custom launcher icon (Android Studio 3.4). This solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I made the silly mistake, I got this error after adding a new XML file in drawable. After going through my recent changes found that my  tag in drawable started with .. and hence ended up with this error. Removed the .. from the start of my <xml tag and issue resolves. :D

Answer (score -1):

update all dependencies from your build gradle issue resolved

Comment: Hey, just a heads up since this is your first post. This is not an answer to the question. It's an instruction that doesn't explain the issue at all. In the future for other people that might come across this, more context is always more helpful.

Comment: by just upgrading my dependency issue solved. will you explain it in proper manner?